# Video is not visible in iframe tag

Tags: html, iframe, youtube-api

I am using Iframe tag to play youtube video on  an embedded box, 
I am getting audio but video is not visible. i am not getting it's hiding or not supporting.
On execution , iframe widget is coming but when i play youtube video it hides the widget.
Below is my code sample of iframe tag.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Comment: How about the code and css from the rest of your page? Video displays for me.
There may be a few things happening. May be something as simple as an overlapping element or wmode.

Comment: Please check your browser console. Does it display anything like `X-Frame-Options`.

Comment: @apoji187 i am running only that much code but not in PC i am running it in an embedded board....@krumia there is no X-frame-Option...